# Error using Latexify.jl: type LotkaVolterra has no field funcs

Tags: julia, differentialequations.jl

I'm trying to follow along with this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPEqYtEd-zY and I encounter the error "type LotkaVolterra has no field funcs" when I run the latexalign function.

I installed ParameterizedFunctions as described here https://github.com/SciML/DiffEqDocs.jl/issues/340 but that did not solve this issue.

I am using Jupyter and I have installed the latest version of Latexify.

```
using DifferentialEquations
using Plots; gr()
using ParameterizedFunctions
using Latexify

lv! = @ode_def LotkaVolterra begin
    dx = a*x -b*x*y
    dy = -c*y + d*x*y
end a b c d
u0 = [1.0,1.0]
p = (1.5, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0)
tspan = (0.0, 10.0)
prob = ODEProblem(lv!, u0, tspan, p)
sol = solve(prob)
plot(sol)
latexalign(lv!)
print(latexalign(lv!))
display(lv!.Jex)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community I added code to the post to reproduce this issue

Comment: As a general suggestion, I wouldn't recommend learning from a 5-year old tutorial - a lot of things in these packages have changed, and Chris (the creator of the tutorial) [recommends in the video comments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPEqYtEd-zY&lc=Ugyg6QnEO7xtxuvr2jh4AaABAg.9dSK9HSXx_79itR00fiY8t) to check out the documentation instead. You can also look at "Tutorial Series 07 | Julia Differential Equations for Beginners" by the channel _doggo dot jl_, and the https://github.com/SciML/SciMLTutorials.jl repository.

Answer (score 1):

That tutorial is just old. Things are much simpler now. Just call `latexify` on it:

```
using ParameterizedFunctions, Latexify

lotka_volterra = @ode_def begin
    dx = a*x -b*x*y
    dy = -c*y + d*x*y
end a b c d

latexify(lotka_volterra)
```

gives:

```
L"\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d} x\left( t \right)}{\mathrm{d}t} =& a x\left( t \right) - b x\left( t \right) y\left( t \right) \\
\frac{\mathrm{d} y\left( t \right)}{\mathrm{d}t} =&  - c y\left( t \right) + d x\left( t \right) y\left( t \right)
\end{align}
"
```